# How should I do to wait all the data downloaded completely and show on TableView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have class named ShowCarClass

It will use TableView to show Car's name and image

```
class ShowCarClass:UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var car = [Car]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func myAPI() {
         startAnimating()
         let json = CarType.Request
         api.getAPIResponse(apiURL:.Car ,jsonType: json) {(isSuccess, result) in

         switch isSuccess {

         case true: 
         let successResult = result as! CarType.Response
         //car array result like this
                 [Car(carName:"BMW",carImg:"https://00.00.00/static/image/BMW.png"),Car(carName:"Audi",carImg:"https://00.00.00/static/image/Audi.png")]
                 self.tableView.delegate = self
                 self.tableView.dataSource = self
                 self.tableView.reloadData()

         case false:
         self.APIErrorStatus(result)
                }
          stopAnimating()
           }
        }
```

When I press Button it can call myApi()  and update tableview content

This ViewController has 3 buttons, it will separately get different data

```
@IBAction func btnPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
         callAPI()
}
```

In function cellForRowAt I use carImg's URL to download Image

```
extension ShowCarClass:UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return car.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CarCell
        cell.carNameLabel.text = car[indexPath.row].carName
        cell.carImageView.downloaded(from:car[indexPath.row].carImg, contentMode: .scaleToFill)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's extension UIImageView

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        guard   let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }

            }
            .resume()
    }

    func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

In ShowCarClass I show startAnimating when call myAPI()

but I need to use image URL to download image

This situation will make start and stop animate finish too quickly

TableView looks like I actually get that data I need

but Car's array content have URL I have to additionally process

I hope it can download all of the image, and implement stopAnimating

Step is like : user open app -> call myApi() -> startAnimating -> All of

the carName and CarImage completely -> stopAnimating -> load into TableView

-> user can see all the car informations (can't swipe tableview until data finished)

I'm really new, not good at questioning if need more info just ask for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DispatchGroup

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

let imageCount = 10

for _ in 1...imageCount{
   dispatchGroup.enter()
   ImageDownloader.download(image: "url") { result in
      dispatchGroup.leave()
   }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where I should put in ?
Do I need to modify my UIImageView extension that's why it can pass image result ?

Comment: in yor  "myAPI" func in result blok, after self.tableView.reloadData(), but now in your cell for row method don't need set image, just show activity indicator. and when all your images downloads reload tableview with exists images